# Should I believe my CPU or laptop manufacturer for maximum memory supported?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu

I am going to buy a laptop which has a i7-6700HQ CPU. As the memory controller is inside the CPU, I thought it would tell the maximum memory supported.

According to Intel:

- Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type)    64 GB
- Memory Types  DDR4-2133, LPDDR3-1866, DDR3L-1600

However, when I check my laptop (Lenovo Y700) tech specs, it says:

- Memory - Up to 16 GB DDR4

Would it be OK to exceed the 16GB amount?

Comment: I'd believe crucial.com - See what their memory configurator says [there are too many "Lenovo Y700" models to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: With only 2 DDR4 slots there is virtually no chance it will support 64GB

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but it does not rule out 32GB (2x 16GB).

Comment: It isn't a question of belief, but interpretation.  They generally don't say bigger memory won't work, they tell you what they know will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequently vendors test compatibility with existing memory modules thats fit. And not update documentation when bigger modules arrive.

But it can be locked in "BIOS".

Look for user expirience.

Lenovo Y700 contains two SO-DIMM slots.
[Users reports upgrade to 32 Gb (2x 16Gb)](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Y700-SSD-and-Memory-upgrade/m-p/3335353#M144218)

Do it on Your own risk. But You risk just in cost of new RAM modules.

Upd.

Chipset maximum memory imply some specific modules configuration. For example: 64M can assume 4*16 Mb but real device can have only one or two memory slots.

Comment: Installed 32GB (2x 16GB Crucial 2133) and it is working perfectly.